# Why does $\frac{\partial X }{\partial \log{Y}} = Y \frac{\partial X}{\partial Y}$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I encountered this identity
$$\cfrac{\partial X }{\partial \log{Y}} = Y \cfrac{\partial X}{\partial Y},$$

but I don't know how to prove it? Any idea??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using chain rule:
$\frac{\partial X}{\partial \log Y}  = \frac{\partial X}{\partial Y} \frac{\partial Y}{\partial \log Y}$

Now set $Z = \log Y$. Then:

$\frac{\partial Y}{\partial \log Y} = \frac{\partial \exp(Z)}{\partial Z} = \exp(Z) = \exp(\log Y) = Y$

Thus we have: $\frac{\partial X}{\partial \log Y}  =  Y\frac{\partial X}{\partial Y}$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$
\frac{\partial X}{\partial \log Y}=\frac{\frac{\partial X}{\partial Y}}{\frac{\partial \log Y}{\partial Y}}
$$